# Get name and value from the input tag

Tags: html, regex

Before you say "oh no, not again" here I'm stating my case. I'm parsing part of HTML output and the only thing I'm interested in is `name` and `value` attributes of each `<input/`> tag. HTML is actually HTML fragment, may not be well-formed. I don't have DOM or HTML parser and I don't try to parse nested elements anyway. The problem is that I don't know the order or number of attributes so it could be `<input name="foo" value="boo"/>` or `<input type="hidden" name=foo>` or `<input id=blah value='boo' src="image.png" name="foo" type="img"/>`.

Is there a single regular expression that would get me values of `name` and `value` attribute in predictable order? I wouldn't have asked the question if I could assume that `name` attribute always precedes `value` but unfortunately this is not the case

Comment: I don't know about you, but *"The problem is that I don't know the order or number of attributes"* would in my world be sufficient reason to use a DOM parser.

Comment: I'm on the platform that has no built in parser and I don't want to bring external one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the values of `name` and `value` into the same capturing group, regardless of order, you could try

```
<input (?=[^>]* name=["']([^'"]*)|)(?=[^>]* value=["']([^'"]*)|)
```

if your regex implementation supports lookaheads.
This assumes that the values are quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using .NET's regular expression syntax:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"
        <input
            (
                \s*
                (?<name>[^=]+)
                =
                (['""])
                (?<value>.*?)
                \2
            )*
        \s*/?>
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(input))
{
    var names = m.Groups["name"];
    var values = m.Groups["value"];

    for(int i = 0; i < names.Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name = {0} Value = {1}",
                names.Captures[i].Value, values.Captures[i].Value);
    }
}
```

For an input string like:

> blah blah <input name="hi" value="world" test='foo' /> blah blah

This will output:

> Name = name Value = hi
>   Name = value Value = world
>   Name = test Value = foo

It doesn't handle `name=value` (i.e. no quotes around the value) but that shouldn't be too hard to add support for.