# Regex: HTML, contents

Tags: html, regex

I'm having a little issue with getting a value of field in HTML using regex.

There is a input tag in the html which is unique and here it is below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="t" value="I-WANT-TO-GET-THIS"/>
```

I would like to know, using REGEX only, how to get "I-WANT-TO-GET-THIS" (without quotes).

Thank-you very much for your time
Paul

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: *"…using REGEX only…"* - Do you also have a good explanation why regex is your only option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get name and value from the input tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926597/get-name-and-value-from-the-input-tag), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058852/regex-to-get-src-value-from-an-img-tag)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp:

```
<input [^>]*?value="([^"]*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

See an working example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/mG8AYSd5A1

Pattern:

```
<input [^>]*? value="(.*)"
```

Comment: ah why? Can you please explain?

Comment: Example: `<input ... value="foo"/><a href="broken.interwebz">`, you would get `foo"/><a href="broken.interwebz`. It's better to use `[^"]*`, but you can also use `.*?`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. But I had opted it only for the example given `input .....`

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it to.

For example: http://www.rubular.com/r/XKUdr9a3jh
it gets the value for inputs even though the name doesn't equal t

Answer (score -1):

How are you doing this? The best idea is to use a HTML parser. Regex with HTML has its own issues, see the link:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)